# What's the proper name for the section of a research paper introduction where you propose a method? Not to be confused with actual Methods section

Tags: publications, writing

I realize there are many ways to structure an introduction. This research paper's introduction has 3 sections: Background and Significance, Relevant Literature, and a third section where I actually propose the method to be explored later in the paper. What is the proper name for that last section of the introduction? Please note, there will be a Methods section next but I still need to introduce an overview of the method in the introduction.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps "Contributions": at least this term, as a paragraph title, is common in my area for what you seem to be referring to.

Comment: Yes, the same in my field too. But also we have papers without an exclusive section title.

Comment: Similarly, "[Our] [main/primary/proposed] contributions:".

Answer (score 2):

Another option I have seen would be for that section to simply carry the name of your method, or a short description of it.

For instance:

***Section 3: The Direct-Section-Name Method.***

***Section 3: A Methodology for Naming Sections Containing the Main Contribution.***

Answer (score 1):

If you use structured titles and well labeled references there is no room for confusing the reader.

**Section 1: Introduction**
Blahing a blah...
**1.4 Proposed method**
Introductory summary of the method you propose.
**Section X: Methods**
**X.1 Method #1**
Description of Method #1...

Then you can use references like "...as mentioned in 1.4...", "...because of limitations in Method #1, following conditions must be met, see X.1..."

If the core purpose of the article is the Method proposal, then the Method should be described appropriately in all following sections:

- Abstract - Very brief summary of why you have developped it and what it returns. (Motivate the plausible readers to read introduction and conclusions)
- Introduction - Not that brief summary of why and what from you have developped it, and briefly how it works. (Assure possible readers they want to read the Conclusions)
- Method proposal - Describe in detail how the method works, what are the inputs and what it returns.
- Discussion - Dicsuss all the upsids and downsides of the method.
- Conclusion - describe briefly how it works and sum up the dicsussion.

Answer (score 0):

Title:

Proposed Method(s):

Results:

Conclusion: